# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'CÓDIGOARTÁCULO' not found

Tags: java, mysql

Al intentar acceder a la base de datos a traves de Java (en Eclipse) me salen estos errores:
'''

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'CÓDIGOARTÍCULO' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:584)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:896)
    at conectarBBDD.Conecta_Acceso_a_BBDD.main(Conecta_Acceso_a_BBDD.java:24)
```

'''
puedo entrar en la base de datos pero no ve las columna, estas columnas están escritas tal cual, en mayúsculas, todo junto y con acentos. Os paso el código por si veis algo que yo no veo, el código es bastante sencillo.

'''

```
package conectarBBDD;
import java.sql.*;

public class Conecta_Acceso_a_BBDD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {           
            Connection miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/curso_java", "xxxx", "****"); //El usuario y el password son correcto
            
            Statement miStatement=miConexion.createStatement();
            
            ResultSet miResultset=miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM productos"); 
            
        
            while(miResultset.next()) { //CON next() COLOCAMOS EL CURSOR EN LA PRIMERA FILA 
                
                System.out.println(miResultset.getString("CÓDIGOARTÍCULO") + " " + miResultset.getString("NOMBREARTÍCULO") + " " + miResultset.getString("PRECIO"))
//Los nombres de las columnas también son correctos     
                
            }
            
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //
        }

    }

}
```

'''

Os agradecería mucho la ayuda, un saludo a tod@s

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, ya lo tengo solucionado, al exportar de excel ha cambiado las columnas por A, B, C, etc... un despropósito.

Comment: que cambiaste? porque lo cambiaste? cual era el problema? como ayuda esto a alguien con el mismo problema?

Comment: Cuando importé los datos de Excel a MySql habían unos nombres de columnas pero no se cogieron los nombres de las columnas, cogió la letra que figura en cada columna:

CODIGOARTICULO | PRECIO | PAISDEORIGEN | ETC...

pero al importarlo, cogió la letra que figura en cada columna del Excel:
A | B | C | etc...

y por eso no me reconocía el nombre de la columna. He cambiado (dentro de la base de datos ya importada) los nombres de las columna:

A = CODIGO ARTICULO | B= PRECI | C= PAISDEORIGEN | etc...

El error ha sido mío por no fijarme como se había importado la hoja de Excel a mi BBDD

Comment: Todo eso deberia estar en la respuesta.. que igual, por como esta planteada, no le va a servir a nadie salvo como referencia, porque era un error que no podiamos detectar nunca por la forma que importaste...

Comment: Es cierto pero hasta que no lo vi no me di cuenta de que el error era de importación y me estaba volviendo loco con el código (y eso que es muy sencillito :)))).  Gracias igualmente por tu interés :)